# how to improve the below query performance in spark?

Tags: postgresql, scala, apache-spark

for my requirement , i will connect to postgres db  and update the bulk data on postgres using spark scala , code is working fine ,but the problem  with performance how can i improve this?
thanks in advacne, Please can anybody help me.

in my code unq_recds coming from list

for that im using below code .

```
val s3 = dbconnection.createStatement()

s3.execute("update "  + db + ".table set column = 'D' , updateddate = CURRENT_DATE where unq_recds in"+ unq_recds"))
```

Comment: Add index on `unq_recds`? Partition the table? Toss spark, and run update directly? Replace table and recreate? Break query into several, and run in parallel? Get rid of postgres and use bigdata/nosql? Shard the database?

Comment: im learning scala  ,sorry what should i do exaclty in spark side ? database not in our control. @Dima thanks for your comment

Comment: @Dima Can you please explain bit longer?

Comment: This is not a scala question. All spark does is send a sql statement to postgres. If anything is slow, it is on the database side. Nothing you can really do about it aside from splitting it into batches and running them in parallel (but even then, your transactions will likely block each other if table is not partitioned). Postgres isn't really a very good tool for huge bulk updates, especially when you cannot "control" the database.